# Setting up an inheritance with Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I've been trying to set up inheritance in my Spring boot project, but I failed to do so. I've tried using the superclass mappings, joined table, single table but still I think I'm missing something. Here is how the classes look like:

Person class:

```
@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "PESEL", nullable = false)
    private Integer pesel;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    private Driver driver;

//setters and getters below
}
```

Driver class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_driver", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    @MapsId
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_driver")
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "license", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String license;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idDriver")
    private Set<Ride> rides = new LinkedHashSet<>();
//setters and getters below
}
```

Here's how it is joined in the database (mysql):

[image: Pic of the db tables]

I would be very thankful if you could at least point me in the right direction (like which inheritance type will suit this simple case the best)

Answer (score 2):

First remove the `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations, as well as the relationship, from your superclass:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_person", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "PESEL", nullable = false)
    private Integer pesel;

//setters and getters below
}
```

Secondly, remove the duplicated `id` column and remove the relationship between the mapped superclass and your derived classes, and actually **extend** the superclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "driver")
public class Driver extends Person{

    @Column(name = "birth_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @Column(name = "license", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String license;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idDriver")
    private Set<Ride> rides = new LinkedHashSet<>();
//setters and getters below
}
```